# Duplicar pagination (react-pagination)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

Estoy intentando duplicar mi componente para la paginacion en la misma pagina pero cada una esta funcionando como un componente independiente.

Es decir me gustaria que al cambiar de pagina en uno de los componente de paginacion, el otro componente de paginacion debe tener el mismo comportamiento y esto no esta sucediendo. Creo que es un problema con class "active". pero no tengo idea de como se hace. Ayuda por favor, Aqui mi codigo

```
const { currentItems, pageCount, handlePageClick } = usePagination( gifs );

<div className="container">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 mb-5">
                        <nav className="d-flex d-flex justify-content-center" aria-label="Page navigation example">
                            <ReactPaginate
                                breakLabel="..."
                                nextLabel="next >"
                                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                                pageCount={pageCount}
                                previousLabel="< previous"
                                renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                                containerClassName="pagination"
                                pageClassName="page-item"
                                activeClassName="active"
                                pageLinkClassName="page-link"
                                previousLinkClassName="page-link"
                                nextLinkClassName="page-link"
                                breakClassName="page-link"
                            />
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
                    {
                        currentItems.map((gif) => (
                            <GifsCard key={ gif.id } { ...gif }/>
                        ))
                    }            
                </div>
                
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <nav className="d-flex d-flex justify-content-center" aria-label="Page navigation example">
                            <ReactPaginate
                                breakLabel="..."
                                nextLabel="next >"
                                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                                pageCount={pageCount}
                                previousLabel="< previous"
                                renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                                containerClassName="pagination"
                                pageClassName="page-item"
                                activeClassName="active"
                                pageLinkClassName="page-link"
                                previousLinkClassName="page-link"
                                nextLinkClassName="page-link"
                                breakClassName="page-link"
                            />
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]